# Two way ANOVA $\sigma^2$ is known. Main effects and interaction

Tags: statistics

I can't solve this question :(

> Suppose that in the two-way ANOVA model the parameter $\sigma^2$ is known. Propose tests (you are allowed to use $\sigma^2$) for the présence of main effects and interactions.

Thank you in advance!!!

Maria

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell us the level of this course and what you have tried. Maybe the following will help, maybe not.

If you didn't know $\sigma^2$, you'd use the F-ratio, 
MS(Treatment)/MS(Error) from a standard ANOVA table.
In this case MS(Error) estimates $\sigma^2.$

If you know $\sigma^2$ there is no need to estimate it.
You could then use the relationship of 
$\text{SS(Treatment)}/\sigma^2$ to a chi-squared distribution
to test whether the population means of the levels of the treatment differ.